# Issue when deliverying report over email. All records are duplicated in attached pdf

Tags: reporting-services

I am experiencing a strange problem in reporting services when I deliver a report over email using subscriptions. I have a report set to be emailed out on a weekly basis with the report attached as a pdf in SSRS 2008. When the report is delivered every record has been doubled up. However when I view the report through the report manager the data is all correct.

This happened last week, so I tried to replicate the error by sending myself various reports and they all seemed to work fine. However this morning when the automated report was sent out again, the attachment once again showed all records with a duplicate record.

Has anyone had this kind of problem? I have not had too much luck on google with it.

Comment: Are you testing against the same database/datasource?

Comment: I am. I deleted the report from report server and re-uploaded the .rdl file. The report has only gone out once since then but it seems to have worked fine. I'm going monitor it for a couple weeks and see if that solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused by having reporting services create a snapshot of the report at the same time that it delivery the subscription. I set them on different schedules which were set to fire a couple minutes from each other and the problem seems to be resolved.

I should note that in my case the data on the report was not very time sensitive (to the day, not to the minute) so the small gap in time would have a minimal effect on data being different in the report that is getting delivered, vs the one stored for historical use.